# redirect with old user input

Tags: php, html, laravel

I am trying to do a check to see if the user has any recorded violations or not.

I have got the flash massage to appear when the user id is entered, but I am having troubles when pressing the button, the entered ID is disappearing, I am trying to reload the page with the previously entered values.

**Here is my view:**

```
<strong>Customer ID:</strong>
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="custidno" id='cust' autocomplete="off" onkeypress="myFunction()"  placeholder="Customer ID" value="{{ old('custidno') }}">
<a class="btn btn-info" href="{{ url('violationcheck') }}">Show</a>
@if(Session::has('flash_message'))
    <div class="alert alert-success"><em> {!! session('flash_message') !!}</em></div>
@endif
```

**and here is my controller:**

```
public function violationcheck(Request $request)
{
    $checked = violation::find($request->custidno);
    if (!empty($checked))
    Session::flash('flash_message','No violations.'); //<--FLASH MESSAGE
else {
    Session::flash('flash_message','Ops, Found some violations.'); //<--FLASH MESSAGE
 }
     return redirect()->route('assignees.create')->withInput();

      }
```

how do I redirect with to previous page and keep user input?

Comment: Show us your full blade file. Especially the form.

Comment: what is the violation:: facade referring to? do you mean validation?

Comment: @CodeBoyCode , i have table called violations.

Comment: aww ok thanks, just checking

Answer (score 0):

Whilst editing the controller code that you submitted about I noticed some missing curly braces in your if statement - try this and let me know if it works:

```
public function violationcheck(Request $request)
{
    $checked = violation::find($request->custidno);

    if (!empty($checked)) {
        Session::flash('flash_message','No violations.'); //<--FLASH MESSAGE
    } else {
        Session::flash('flash_message','Ops, Found some violations.'); //<--FLASH MESSAGE
    }
     return redirect()->route('assignees.create')->withInput();
}
```